# how do I track my wallet transfer?

Tags: transactions, wallets

Can someone help me. I was looking to see whats taking so long from coinbase to my wallet and I found this on redit. So how do i track my transaction from my wallet from coinbase to my other wallet? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To view the transaction on the network, go to the Coinbase dashboard and click the withdrawal under "Recent Activity". Then click "View transaction", which opens up the tx in Etherscan in another tab.